# Transfering token using @solana/spl-token ts sdk createTransferCheckedInstruction

Tags: spl-token

I am trying to transfer a token between 2 wallets using @solana/spl-token.

```
import { Token, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } from '@solana/spl-token';

const walletId = new PublicKey(wallet);
const { blockhash } = await conn.getLatestBlockhash("processed"); //finalized

let transaction = new Transaction();
transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
transaction.feePayer = walletId;

transaction.add(Token.createTransferCheckedInstruction(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, fromNftAta, nftId, toNftAta, walletId, [], 1, 0));
```

The code on execution gives

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createTransferCheckedInstruction')
```

Any idea as to where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Token` class is from an older version of the JS package.  If you're using a newer version, you can directly import the instruction creator, ie:

```
import { createTransferCheckedInstruction, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } from '@solana/spl-token';
```